# Returning Observer from a custom function via service : Angular 4

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am new to Observer in Angular4 as I have worked on Promises in `AngularJs`. I want to understand 2 scenarios:

1. Returning observable from a function so that the UI can be changed accordingly.
2. Returning continuous stream of data from a function which is reflected on the UI.

In a service (proc.svc.ts) file I created a function:

```
counter(){
   public counterObserver = Observable.create(obs => {
    obs.next(increment())
   });
  return counterObserver;
 }

increment(){
  setInterval(function(){
  count++
 },1000)
}
```

In the proc.component.ts file:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.initCounter();
 }

initCounter(){
  this.procSvc.counter.subscribe(count => this.count = count);
}
```

I am getting below error:

> Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '() => void'.

Comment: You created a function : call `counter()`, not `counter` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seem like problem with the code also , if you want to push value at specific interval than you have to push vlaue on ovserver , like as given below push value from setInterval() function , that is also problem with you code

```
const evenNumbers = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
  let value = 0;
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (value % 2 === 0) {
      observer.next(value);
    }
    value++;
  }, 1000);

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
});
//output: 0...2...4...6...8
const subscribe = evenNumbers.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

one more thing as in example its directly subscribing to oberserver not function there is no () present but in you case its fuction as i pointed out below

---

try like this , as counter is function and that is problem with you code seems like

```
initCounter(){
  this.procSvc.counter().subscribe(count => this.count = count);
}
```

---

you have to provide return type here

```
counter(): Observable<datatype>{
```

right now it seems empty that means void. or i do as below when datatype is not known

```
 public getData(path: string):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(path, options)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())  ;
  }
```

then aply subscribe on that

```
 getData("val").subscribe();
```

also import

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Comment: @Samuel - that is to dispose timer..means when you unsubscribe observer than this function clear the timer that you creaed..check example here : https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/create.html

Comment: @Samuel - you can see here : https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/76